# Manipulating an object inside a method

Tags: java, object, methods, global-variables, pass-by-reference

I am trying to manipulate an object inside a method like this:

**My class `Problem`:**

```
public class TaxiProblem {

public Problem(final World world, final Agent agent) {
        _world = world;
        _world.setRandomAgent(_agentPlace);
    }

private Place _agentPlace;

// Various other functions

}
```

and in the function `.setRandomAgent()` in the class `World` I am trying to manipulate the `Place` object in what I want it to be like this:

```
public void setRandomAgent(Place agentPlace) {
        int rand = _random.nextInt(25);
        agentPlace = _places.get(rand);
        agentPlace.setHasAgent(true);
    }
```

I basically want to grab a random `Place` from the List `_places` and have it in the variable `agentPlace` in `.setRandomAgent()` which in turn will have it in `_agentPlace` in the `Problem` class. I thought this would work since Java passes objects by reference in methods but it didn't and `_agentPlace` remains null.

Comment: Java passes parameters by value, not by reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Answer (score 2):

By doing this

```
agentPlace = _places.get(rand);
```

you are overwriting the reference that was passed to the method and losing access to the object you want to alter.

In your `setRandomAgent` method, `agentPlace` is indeed a reference that points to your `_agentPlace` field, not the field itself. In the line I pasted above, what you do is make that reference point to a different object.

Answer (score 1):

```
_agentPlace = _world.getRandomAgent();


public Place getRandomAgent() {
        int rand = _random.nextInt(25);
        Place agentPlace = _places.get(rand);
        agentPlace.setHasAgent(true);
        return agentPlace();
    }
```

When you pass `agentPlace` to the method, you are creating a copy of the reference. So if you modify the object, then it would work when you return up the stack. But reassigning the variable makes you lose the object you were working with.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your problem lies in the implementations as your understanding of pass by reference I believe is correct. The following code will produce the results you expect - That is, it will first print "Before change", then "I am changed!".

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var problem = new Problem();
    }
}


public class Problem
{
    public Problem()
    {
        var toChange = new ClassToChange();
        toChange.ChangeMe = "Before change";
        Console.WriteLine(toChange.ChangeMe);

        var changer = new ClassThatChanges();
        changer.ChangeSomething(toChange);
        Console.WriteLine(toChange.ChangeMe);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class ClassToChange
{
    public string ChangeMe { get; set; }
}

public class ClassThatChanges
{
    public void ChangeSomething(ClassToChange classToChange)
    {
        classToChange.ChangeMe = "I am changed!";
    }
}
```